# Recording a video with Yamaha P115?

Tags: recording, keyboard

I have a Yamaha P115 keyboard and I'd like to record videos of myself playing, like Kyle Landry on YouTube. I have TASCAM TH-02 headphones that I plug in to my keyboard, but otherwise, that's everything I have right now.

Is there a way to film a video of me playing from my iPad with no background interference and edit them on my iPad as well? I currently edit using Pinnacle Studio on my iPad, and I'd like for it to stay that way. I DO NOT want to buy a computer for this. Could someone give some advice to the things I would need to buy in order to do all of this?

Also, is Synthesia somehow linked with this and would I need a subscription? I barely know anything about this type of stuff, so it's pretty hard to know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to get clean audio would be to record through the headphone jack on your iPad. This is a [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3991995?tstart=0) on how to do that.

You'll probably also want a headphone splitter so you can listen to yourself play while you record.

Edit: This answer (from "Scott O", taken from [here](http://www.apple.com/hk/shop/question/answers/readonly/tag/iphone/can-my-iphone-6-record-a-video-with-audio-from-the-lineinheadphone-jack/QHPYUUXU4Y2DX49KX)) might be a better resource on how to record through the headphone jack:

> So what you need to get is a TRRS to TS cable which will look
>   like a cable with a plug that goes into your phone that has a TRRS
>   end... it will then have to ends which can accept headphones on one
>   side and a mic or audio source on the other allowing you to plug a
>   dynamic mic or cable with the appropriate plug size and a headphone
>   into the other side for monitoring (if the app supports it). You can
>   also find these cables where there is no headphone jack and only a
>   straight thru TRRS to TS cable for simply plugging in a TS mic cable
>   to the iPhone6+. You can get these cables on amazon very
>   inexpensively.

Comment: No splitter required. The P115 has two 1/4" headphone jacks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to record like that guy, the first thing you need is a video camera.

Then, as you can see in his videos, it is not possible to hear anything except the music, so he is not recording with a microphone.

There are two possibilities:

1 - He records direct audio signal though the jack output. Then maybe he edits whatever background/signal noise with audacity filters and synchronises the audio with the recorded movie.

2 - He records the midi output of whatever he has played, makes some adjusts in the midi (a little fixing here and there), assigns a cool piano instrument to that midi (there are piano samples os several gigabytes out there), and synchronises the audio with the recorded movie.

By the way, I have your same keyboard. I feel a drop in quality with the headphones, for some reason. Maybe the room acoustics improves the sound or whatever.

Comment: Better headphones make a big difference.